# Neo4j shortest_path documentation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

There is so little info on the full set of parameters and a exhaustive list of examples, like when the cost in a relationship is a property of the relationship. The most I found was this but it has barely any info on it: https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/openCypher9.pdf

I wish there was something like the Linux man pages. Even the neo4j "official" docs have a few examples without the full parameter lst. Anyone know anything better?

Comment: See this: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/pathfinding/

Comment: Are you interested in finding unweighted shortest paths (least amount of hops between two nodes) or weighted shortest paths (cheapest path based on some cost/weight)? Vanilla Cypher only supports the former, for weighted shortest path, you need to use a stored procedure, e.g. one provided by the Graph Data Science library.

Comment: Weighted shortest path based on some weight that is a property of the relationship. For example say people are connected by roads, and the length of that road is that I want to be as the weight. Guess I am out of luck then.

Comment: What is wrong with apoc shortest path algorithms? must it be pure cypher?

Comment: What do you mean